# X Windowing System Servers for Windows 7 - 64 bit

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, x-server

Due to WinRot I was forced into an unplanned Windows 7 upgrade.  I am in the process of obtaining tools that I was using on Win XP Pro.

One item that I am lacking at this point is an X Windowing System server for my new system.

I am looking at standard commercial offerings as well as others.

I was looking for the wisdom from all of you as to which packages to examine, compare and select from.  And Recommendations....etc...

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I commonly use & highly recommend [Xming](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/).

Answer (score 1):

Cygwin...nuff said

Comment: I have read that Cygwin/X does not work on a 64 bit Win 7 system.

Comment: it can and will if you use it as a 32-bit app...i can run it on x64

Answer (score 1):

[Cygwin/X](http://x.cygwin.com/) has always done it for me when I needed a X server on Windows.

Comment: I have read that Cygwin/X does not work on a 64 bit Win 7 system.

Comment: @mpdc: Show us.

Comment: I just tried Cygwin/X and found it generated some STACK OVERFLOW issues.  It was VERY VERY slow coming up and running on my system (3.3 GHz Dual Xeon processors, hyperthreading ON, 4 GB memory) , and I found it to cause problems in the Windows 7 systems operation itself which forced me to reboot.  So this does not look like a good match for running on this system.

Answer (score 0):

I've used both Xming and Cygwin/X. However, for 64-bit Windows 7 and above, there really is one Open Source choice - VcXsrv Windows X Server

https://sourceforge.net/projects/vcxsrv

- It's an MS Windows X11 server based on the xorg git sources (like xming or cygwin's xwin)
- It is actively updated (at the time of this posting)
- It accounts for 64-bit Win7 & above and dropped the old XP cruft
- It's compiled with VC++ 2012 Express Edition, not 'mingw' (And also can be with VS2008, VS2008 Express Edition and VS2010 Express Edition - because they keep somewhat current/moving forward.)
- It includes all fonts and DPI that I'm aware of
- Properly supports multiple monitors - even with different orientations

BTW. If after install when trying to start VcXsrv you get the error below, it's because you're missing a MS Visual C++ Redistributable 2015. This isn't the only application with this error. Notepad++ and others have it too.

> The program can't start because api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1.0.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem

Here's the fix (update, else get a MS download): http://blog.spreendigital.de/2015/09/01/how-to-fix-the-api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0-dll-is-missing-error-for-delphi-10-seattle/